# Why is SSL not working with web proxy (Charles)?

Tags: proxy, https

I've been using Charles to inspect the https traffic between an app I'm developing and the api. Everything works. Now the api changed the host and I can't inspect the traffic anymore. I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer` in the app. It works however without the proxy. I assume there's something special with this backend that is blocking the proxy. The emulator is always the same and I haven't changed the settings. What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API host has changed, its likely that the owner has implemented a newer SSL configuration which is now longer compatible with your Charles proxy.

I would suspect SNI support may be the issue here.

A lot of people rely on SNI now to allow them use multiple SSL certificates on the same infrastructure, but that means support for non-SNI implementations is removed.

What that means is that your client isn't specifying `servername` in the HTTPS handshake.

Most up to date software includes SNI support, but it's possible that your Charles installation is out of date and using an older `openssl` library that doesn't support SNI.

That said, it could also be minimal TLS version, namely that the host now requires a minimal TLS version of 1.2, and Charles is using 1.1.

Whatever the case, if the API works without the proxy, the issue is the `openssl` library in Charles.